# google maps v3 zoom to fit all markers(path) function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, zooming

I've put together a little snippet on js fiddle so you can see what I am working with.

Basically I am trying to hook up a "Zoom" button so that once a path is created you can click the zoom button and the map zooms to fit the path.  All of the answers I have found work by having an array of markers which I do not have.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/A3NBZ/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, in fact you *do* have an array of markers! It's stored in the `Polyline` that you're creating when the user is clicking on the map. To retrieve the points on which the user has clicked, simply use [`Polyline.getPath()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polyline). You can then add those points (as geocodezip mentioned) to a `LatLngBounds` object and use [`google.maps.Map.fitBounds()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) to adjust the map view to the given bounds.

Here's a simple implementation of the zoom method, based on the code example you've provided (you can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kaktus621/svLUn/1/)).

```
function zoom() {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  geodesic.getPath().forEach(function(latLng) {
    bounds.extend(latLng);
  });
  map.fitBounds(bounds);                    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the examples you have seen with markers, add all the google.maps.LatLngs in the path to a google.maps.LatLngBounds object (using bounds.extend()), then call map.fitBounds on the resulting bounds object.

[updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g37HE/)

Comment: I'm sorry, could you elaborate just a bit for me, I'm kinda new to js and the api.

Comment: added a jsfiddle that extends the bounds with each point and uses map.fitBounds(bounds).